# Using PHP/MySQL to loop through checked checkboxes and insert into database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP form with 4 text fields and 2 checkboxes. The checkboxes are "tags" that can be applied to the articles that are input using the text fields.

For example:

Information:

**Title** - Defining intransitive relationships of the migratory birds of South America

**Author** - Author. S. Wellington

**Access Date** - 19/06/2012

**URL** - http://www.wellington.org/articles/birds/def-int-rel-mig-bird-s-amer.pdf

Tags:

Birds[X]   South America[X]

In this case both of the checkboxes would be checked, because the article pertains both to birds and South America.

I have a database with 3 tables in it:

**articles:** id - articletitle - articleorganization - articledate - articleurl

**tags:** id - tag_content

**articles_tags:** article_id - tag_id

Currently, my form can insert the article information into the articles table using:

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO articles SET articletitle='$articletitle',
      articleorganization='$articleorganization',
      articledate='$articledate',
      articleurl='$articleurl' ")
```

and then, I can use `$article_id = mysql_insert_id();` to get the id that would be inserted into the articles_tags table.

But after that I am totally stumped.

I need to somehow loop over the checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="articletags_birds" value="Birds" id="articletags_0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="articletags_southamerica" value="South America" id="articletags_1" />
```

but I have no idea how I should be doing that.

Comment: Loop over POST and compare index names to "articletags". This way you will loop over all articletags_ POST variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($_POST['articletags_birds'] == 'on')
{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO tags SET id='$article_id', tag_content='articletags_birds'");
}
```

Do the same for the other tags. If you have a very large number (5+), or want users to input their own tags, just do something like:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value)
{
    if (strpos($key, 'articletags_') === 0) //identity, otherwise false will set this off
    {
         mysql_query("INSERT INTO tags SET id='$article_id', tag_content='$value'");
    }
}
```

Note:

1.) There will be no POST sent if there is no checkbox selected!

2.) strpos will check if the tag starts with articletags_

3.) please ESCAPE the the queries! I've just shorthanded it all, but malicious PHP can be injected here

Comment if I'm unclear / if its still not working

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% what your problem is
but:

1. Offcourse I would keep Tag names in database
2. Then when generating a form to update article 
   i would get all tags from database and insert them in loop like this:

   ```
   <input type="checkbox" name="tagArray[]" value = '$tagId' />$tagName
   ```
3. Then after submitting a form i would
   check in loop if any of these tags are set in post request and
   create new articles_tags
   like this:

   ```
   if(isset($_POST['tagArray']))
   {
    $tagArray = $_POST['tagArray'];
        foreach($tagArray as $tagId)
        {
          mysql_query('...');
          // insert new articles_tags with tag_id = $tagId and article_id =$article_id
         }     
   }
   ```